# Loopback 4 openapi nswag make filter optional and get type

Tags: typescript, loopbackjs, openapi, loopback4, nswag

I'm facing the issue that the Loopback 4 `filter` that is created on the generated endpoints is marked as required in my Nswag typescript generated file. This needs to be optional. But i can't find where it's coming from.

The endpoint from my `controller`

```
@get('/', {
    operationId: 'getPages',
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Array of Page model instances',
        content: {
          'application/json': {
            schema: {
              type: 'array',
              items: getModelSchemaRef(Page, {includeRelations: true}),
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })
  async find (
    @param.filter(Page) filter?: Filter<Page>,
  ): Promise<Page[]> {
    return this.pageRepository.find(filter);
  }
```

It is marked as optional (`filter?: Filter<Page>`)

The generated code for this endpoint

```
getPages (filter: any | undefined): Promise<PageWithRelations[]> {
    let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/pages?";
    if (filter === null)
      throw new Error("The parameter 'filter' cannot be null.");
    else if (filter !== undefined)
      url_ += "filter=" + encodeURIComponent("" + filter) + "&";
    url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

    let options_ = <RequestInit>{
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json"
      }
    };

    return this.http.fetch(url_, options_).then((_response: Response) => {
      return this.processGetPages(_response);
    });
  }
```

Also shown in the `getPages` function is that the `filter` has a type of `any | undefined`. I dont mind the `undefined` (i know where it's coming from). But why isn't the type of the `filter` defined as the properties type (`filter: Filter`). The interface is exported but somehow not related to the property

```
export interface Filter {
  offset?: number;
  limit?: number;
  skip?: number;
  order?: string[];
  fields?: Fields;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getPages (filter: any | undefined): Promise<PageWithRelations[]> {
 // ...
}
```

As far as I understand TypeScript, the signature `filter: any | undefined` is equivalent to `filter?: any`, i.e. the argument is already marked as optional.

> But why isn't the type of the filter defined as the properties type (`filter: Filter`). The interface is exported but somehow not related to the property.

This may be a limitation of Nswag. How is `filter` parameter described in the OpenAPI spec generated by your LoopBack application? Can you please post the relevant Parameter object?